# why code used 2 pointer variables

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int s[4][2]={
            {1234,56},
            {1212,33},
            {1434,80},
            {1312,78},
            };
int (*p)[2];
int i,j,*pint;
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    p=&s[i];
    pint=(int *)p;
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<=1;j++)
    printf("%d\t",*(pint+j));
}
return 0;            
}
```

In this code snippet the programmer used two pointer variable 'p' and 'pint'? can't I get result by using only 'p' variable ?

Comment: Neither `p` nor `pint` are required here...

Comment: You can use either `p` or `pint` or both or neither; your choice.  On the whole, neither is the best choice.  The printing could do with a newline at the end.  The cast is brutal.  It works, but that's about all you can say for it.  The type correct assignment is `pint = *p;`.

Comment: this is just a practice question in topic named 'pointers in arrays' so I have to do this using pointers only.

Comment: @Neeraj Actually Do you want to get array values using `p` variable??

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR I want to get array by using only one variable either p or pint

Comment: @Neeraj Your question is that can't I get result by using only 'p' variable? So only i posted one program using only `p` variable (i.e) pointer to array variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes only `p` is enough  checkout here : **(Note : it depends on purpose they might be trying to understand the pointer concepts)**

```
int main()
{
 int s[4][2]={
            {1234,56},
            {1212,33},
            {1434,80},
            {1312,78},
            };
int (*p)[2];
int i,j;
p=s;
 for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
 {
  for(j=0;j<=1;j++)
    printf("%d\t",p[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
 }
return 0;            
}
```

In your code they are trying to explain how a to create `2D pointer` and how this `2D pointer` can points the a `row` from `2D array`; here `p=&s[i];` `p` points the 1st row of 2D array `s`. now `pint=(int *)p;` here an `int` pointer `pint` is pointing the 1st row of your 2D array `s`. and finally printing value by using pointer `pint` as  `*(pint+j)`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `p` and `pint` serve rather redundant tasks as intermediary variables. You are correct that you can achieve the same result without `pint`, but you can also achieve the same result without either `p` or `pint`.

In my experience, `for` loops are better written as `for (i = start; i < end; i++)` rather than `for (i = start; i <= end - 1; i++)`. With this in mind, an example of the code that doesn't utilise `p` or `pint` might be:

```
int main()
{
    int s[4][2]={
                {1234,56},
                {1212,33},
                {1434,80},
                {1312,78},
                };

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            printf("%d\t", s[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;            
}
```

When used in an expression, array types often *decay* to a pointer type that points to the first element. It is crucial to understand that array types and pointer types are still distinct. There are cases where array types don't decay to pointer types, in particular, when it is the operand to `sizeof` or `&`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print array elements using pointer to array variable.. TRy this...

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     int main()
     {
        int s[4][2]={
        {1234,56},
        {1212,33},
        {1434,80},
        {1312,78},
                   };
         int (*p)[2];
         int i,j;
         p=s;
         for(i=0;i<=3;i++)        
         {          
           for(j=0;j<=1;j++)
           printf("%d\t",p[i][j]);//(or) printf("%d\t",*(*(p+i)+j));
           printf("\n");
         }
         return 0;            
       }
```